# How to cast dynamically in java with the usual brackets?

Tags: java, dynamic, casting

Or is it even possible? I'm writing a `REST client` at the time. There is the `URLConnection` class in java which is extended by `HttpURLConnection` and `HttpsURLConnection`.
What I'd like is declare a type `(HttpURLConnection or HttpsURLConnection)` and cast this `URLConnection` object based on a boolean value to that declared type. F.e:

```
Class<? extends URLConnection> theClass = _SSL ? 
    HttpsURLConnection.class : HttpURLConnection.class;
```

then

```
((theClass) HttpConnection).setRequestMethod("POST");
```

or something similar.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want a `Class` object or an object for performing HTTP operations?

Comment: The example you show demonstrates no good reason to dynamically cast. `HttpsURLConnection` is a subclass of `HttpURLConnection` and you are calling the base class method.

Comment: I might be using bad phrases, sorry for that. I don't want Class object, I just want to cast that object by a variable.

Comment: You can't. Java is a strongly typed language. It's unclear why you would think this is a good idea, there is likely to be a better solution whatever you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @MikkelLøkke "strongly" != "statically", and this is about the latter.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Java does not, as far as I'm aware, have a version of the dynamic type, you have in for instance C#. Doing this is Java would likely require several instance of checks or similar. So how you would explicitly cast something to a class it may not be a type of is beyond me.

Comment: There's no need to cast at all. You have an abstract base class URLconnection which defines the capabilities (available methods) of such a connection (this is the vehicle), then you have the HttpURLConnection (a car) and a HttpsURLConnection (a truck). Objects that are of one of the subclasses are aware of their type. So you can simply ask the object to do something, like setRequestMethod() without having to know the exact type of the object.

Comment: @MikkelLøkke How does your comment correlate to what I said? If anything, you have confirmed that you meant "statically" (opposite of "dynamically") and not "strongly" typed. Strong typing is a given in most modern languages, be they static or dynamic.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I misunderstood your comment. I thought you were implying that Java is not statically typed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you only need to cast to `java.net.HttpURLConnection` because your `HttpsURLConnection` and `HttpURLConnection` both extend this abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
if(_SSL) {
    ((HttpsURLConnection) HttpConnection).setRequestMethod("POST");
} else {
    ((HttpURLConnection) HttpConnection).setRequestMethod("POST");
}
```

As [szidijani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2545756/szidijani) commented, there is no need of `Class` object.